# Building an Edit Form in React and having trouble setting hook

Tags: reactjs, forms, react-hooks

So, I am building out an Edit Form for a React project, and decided to create a custom hook, to store the initial state of the data and then update changes for it to be submitted. However, whenever I pass in initial state, the fields hook gets the id of the fields, but clears the value of the fields. My console log on for initialState returns the correct object, and the console log for fields returns an object where everything is set to 0 or false. Any help would be appreciated!

```
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

export function useFormFields(initialState) {
  const [fields, setValues] = useState(initialState);

  console.log(initialState);
  console.log(fields)



  return [
    fields,
    function(event) {
      setValues({
        ...fields,
        [event.target.id]: event.target.value,
      });
    },
  ];
}
```

Comment: Can you add a codesandbox link or reproduce the issue in this codesandbox https://codesandbox.io/s/pensive-butterfly-h6vo3?

Comment: Where is `event` coming from? How are you using this hook?